# How to solve the overlapping of vertex in igraph?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

Given a data frame:

```
v1         v2
a          b
a          c
d          b
d          c
c          a
```

I tried to plot a network with `igraph`:

```
g = graph.data.frame(df, directed=F)
layout <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(g, layout=layout, edge.arrow.size = 0, edge.color = "gray80", vertex.label = NA)
```

But a very bad result is given:

[image]

I tried to set the length of the edge directly but seems that there is no such function. And I have tried almost every methods in others' tutorials but all of them did not work. I am nearly crazy about that. Could you please tell me how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could reduce the vertex size the avoid overlapping, e.g. `g <- ba.game(200); par(mfrow=c(1,2), cex=.25); plot(g, vertex.label=NA, edge.arrow.size = 0); plot(g, vertex.size=.5, vertex.label = NA, edge.arrow.size = 0)`.

Comment: @lukeA, Thanks for your answer! Can I use par() to set the area used to plot the graph? Seem that now it just use part of it.

Comment: `?igraph.plotting` - have you tried `asp=0`? In addition, you can set `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))`.

Comment: @lukeA the ratio is more proper, but I don't know why the graph just show on half of the plots.

Comment: @lukeA It did not until I set the value of `par` as you did. Could please help me to change it to default value?

Comment: `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)); plot(g, asp=0)` takes the full width and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101573/discussion-between-lukea-and-user5779223).